# MIPSアセンブリコード内の"jal"が動きません。対処法を教えてください。

Tags: assembly, mips

私は乗算を行うMIPSのアセンブリコードを書きました。（下のコードです）
しかし、main文中で乗算を行う関数を表すラベル、"mult"に"jal"を用いて行くようにしましたが、Qtspimで確認したところ、動きませんでした。
それの対処法および、改善点等明示して頂けますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
.globl main
main:
    addi $sp,$sp,-16 #スタック上で4語分のスペースを取る
    sw $s0,12($sp) #$s0を退避する
    sw $s1,8($sp) #$s1を退避する
    sw $s2,4($sp) #$s2を退避する
    sw $ra,0($sp) #$raを退避する
    add $s0,$zero,$zero #$s0 = 0
L1:
    .data
str:
    .asciiz "\nEnter two positive integer a,b "
    .text
    li $v0,4 #print_stringのシステムコールコード4を$v0にロード
    la $a0,str #asciizで保存した文字列のアドレスを$a0に格納
    syscall #実行

    li $v0,1 #print_int
    li $s1,5 #read_intのシステムコード5を$s1にロード
    syscall #実行

    li $v0,1 #print_int
    li $s2,5 #read_intのシステムコード5を$s2にロード
    syscall #実行

    jal mult #multへジャンプする
    j L1 #L1へジャンプする
End:
mult:
    beq $t0,$zero,end #$t0 ≠ 0 ならラベルendに行く
    $s0 = $s0 + $s2 #r = r + y
    addi $t1,&zero,1 #$t1 = 1
    beq $s1,$t1,end1 #$s1 = 1ならラベルend1に行く
end1:
    lw $ra,0($sp) #$raを戻す
    lw $s2,4($sp) #$s2を戻す
    lw $s1,8($sp) #$s1を戻す
    lw $s0,12($sp) #$s0を戻す
    addi $v0,$zero,$s0 #$v0 = $s0
end:
    jal half #halfへジャンプ
    add $s2,$s2,$s2 #$s2 = $s2 + $s2
    lw $ra,0($sp) #$raを戻す
    lw $s2,4($sp) #$s2を戻す
    lw $s1,8($sp) #$s1を戻す
    lw $s0,12($sp) #$s0を戻す
    addi $v0,
odd:
    andi $t0,$s0,0x1 #$t0 = $s0 & 0x1
    jr $ra
half:
srl $s1,Ss1,1 #$s1を右に1シフト
    jr $ra
```

Comment: `Note that, you can't create a label with the same name as a MIPS instruction. ` なので、`mult` を別の名前に変更してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど、MIPSで用意されている機能と同じ名前ではいけなかったのですね。直したらうまく動きました。

Comment: このコードでmultとラベルした関数ないで、r = r + yという動作を行なっている行の命令が実行されません。原因は何か教えて頂けますでしょうか？

Comment: MIPS のアセンブラは全く分からないのですが、そこは `add $0,$0,$2` とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね。よく見たらC言語で書いていました。丁寧に回答してくださりありがとうございます。

Comment: @metropolis さん、回答としてご投稿頂けないでしょうか？